# Transpose rows/columns in SQL result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have found many answers to this question, but all of them leave me stymied as to actually making it work. Apparently, I am just being dense today.  Can someone just give me the code to make this work?

My T-SQL query returns the following rows:

Before

[image]

I need to transpose the rows and columns:

Like this

[image]

Comment: The word for that is pivot. What database?

Comment: PS: I cannot know the full list of PRODUCT_CODE until the initial query has generated a result set.

Comment: It is a SQL database.  I have studied the PIVOT function but just cannot get the result that I am looking for.

Comment: Can you edit your post and put the actual SQL/Pivot samples you saw, or at least tried?  Someone will be better able to help show you where the error was in what you tried, THEN explain the how/why.

Answer (score 1):

unpivot —> pivot

```
select p.*
from
(
    --My T-SQL query returns the following rows:
    select *
    from
    (
    values
    ('A',1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),('B',10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80),
    ('C',100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800), ('I',11,22,33,0,0,0,0,88)
    ) as t(product_code,week_1,week_2,week_3,week_4,week_5,week_6,week_7,week_8)
) as s
unpivot
(
thevalue for weekno in (week_1,week_2,week_3,week_4,week_5,week_6,week_7,week_8)
) as u
pivot
(
max(thevalue) for product_code in (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J)
) as p;
```

Comment: Umm, could you make that work with a dynamic list of PRODUCT_CODEs?